# Prepare specific data before generating report

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, reporting

```
SectionNumber  Metric Number  SLAName (database field) SLA Type(DB field)
1                  1            TVQ Complete process    A
1                  2            TVQ Complete process    B
1                  3            TVQ Complete process    A
1                  4            TVQ Complete process    A
```

I want to group by Section number and Metric numbers. But I have to bind with the SLA Name. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to group by what? SLAName?

Comment: can you be more clear about what you want to do?

Comment: FIrst I want to form Data like I have Mentioned i.e. With SLA name I have to join Section Number and Metric Number. Once I have this then I will have to group the data on SectionNumber + Metric Number + SLAName.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports : How to write formula field for this report and make grouping on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490355/crystal-reports-how-to-write-formula-field-for-this-report-and-make-grouping-o)

Comment: This is the same Problem but I just rectified the content and made it simpler.